# Message "An error has occurred" when use webapi with JWT in IIS 8.5

Tags: c#, jwt, webapi, windows-server-2012-r2, iis-8.5

I have a webapi in C# and use JWT authentication in Windows Server 2012 R2 with IIS 8.5.
This webapi works fine in others servers (with IIS 10), but when I call in IIS 8.5 return the message "An error has occurred".
This error return when I call methods with JWT. I tryed to put AllowAnonymous, but, if I have some validation with JWT, occur the error.
When I call others methods (with no JWT validations), work fine.
If I call the same method in localhost, in the server, return a empty download (!) instead of the real return (is a test message) or the error.

Does have any configuration in IIS or i my application I need to do???
Someone does have any idea for me???

This is the error message

[Error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D8cHl.png)

The method is a GET method and I tested with a Xamarin Form, browser and Postman.

I expect a message when I call the method.
After this result, I can try to test the others methods (authentication, POST, etc.).

This is the expect result
[Expect result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0DMEW.png)

Comment: Check server side logs

Comment: IIS 8.5 just went end of life. So if you can, let it rest in peace.

Comment: as Lex Li said use the latest version of the iis. if you still want to troubleshoot1) enable iis detailed error message to get more detail. 2)check event viewer logs 3)share some sample code and web.config file 4)use tool like fiddler for the troubleshooting